# ROS - rqt - python: Fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server :0.0

Tags: python, ros, rqt

I am learning the basics of ROS (Kinetic) by following the tutorials at http://wiki.ros.org. I am running Ubuntu on Windows 10 and using Xming for GUI. Also, I only know basics of Ubuntu. All was going good until I reached this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch - **Using rqt_console and roslaunch** -. When I entered following command

```
$ rosrun rqt_logger_level rqt_logger_level
```

It worked fine for the first time. But when I closed the window and ran the same command again I  got the following error:-

**python: Fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server :0.0.**

Later I found that any command involving rqt gives me the exact same error. However everything else including graphical programs and widgets are running absolutely fine.

I have tried removing rqt and reinstalling but nothing helps.

I have searched a lot for this error, but can't find any specific info regarding Fatal IO error 2 and what is causing it.

I have also tried following commands and all give same error:-

```
$ rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph

$ rosrun rqt_console rqt_console

$ rqt
```

Can anyone please help with this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. so after struggling for a few hours after this post I checked out rqt -h which showed me all available options including **--clear-config**. which is suppose to clear the configuration (including all perspectives and plugin settings). So I did this:-

```
rqt --clear-config
```

and then

```
rqt_graph --clear-config
```

and one of these did the trick. Hope this helps someone.